# Python pandas: "can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>"

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df: `df_jan_2001` and `df_feb_2001`. I would like to do a full outer join by using this syntax:

```
new_df = pd.merge('df_jan2001', 'df_feb2001', how='outer', left_on=
['designation', 'name'], right_on=['designation', 'name'])
```

`designation` and `name` are both string variables.

Why do I get the following error and how can I fix it?

```
"ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>"
```

Sorry if this is a basic question, just getting started with pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOU can try like this.

```
new_df = pd.merge(df_jan2001, df_feb2001, how='outer', left_on=['designation', 'name'], right_on=['designation', 'name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `new_df = pd.merge(df_jan2001.to_frame(), df_feb2001.to_frame(), how='outer', left_on=['designation', 'name'], right_on=['designation', 'name'])`

Answer (score 0):

There is problem `'df_jan2001'` is `string`, `df_jan2001` is here `DataFrame`.

If columns are same in both `DataFrame`s, use parameter `on` only:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df_jan2001, df_feb2001, how='outer', on=['designation', 'name'])
```