# "ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>" when merging two data frames with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I merging two data frames by two columns with the same column name

```
results = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='gene',how='outer',indicator=True)
```

I have seen the same problem here

[Python pandas: "can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127961/python-pandas-can-not-merge-dataframe-with-instance-of-type-class-str?rq=1)

but even using the few different ways suggested, the same error always appears.

I haven't found useful info on the internet.

I think it is not necessary show df1 and df2 but if requested I can tried (working in a cluster without internet)

EDIT:

I can't copy and paste code but I can do a screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample of df1 and df2.

Comment: Just in case, please make sure both `print(type(df1))` and `print(type(df2))` show `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: proivide a minimal reproducible sample of your relevant code

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have edited the question adding what was requested. df1 is genes_affected and df2 is LOEUF